# Possible to send password in plain text with SHA-256?

Tags: security, sha256

I just registered on a site where I had to specify sensitive information, eg. my card number. I got a confirmation mail where my password was in plain text. I learned that password should NEVER be in plain text. If they can, that means that my sensitive information are stored in plain text too.

I contacted their support and they claim that they are using the encryption method SHA-256 for the passwords. Is it safe? Is it still possible to send plain text password even after encryption?

Comment: SHA-256 is technically a one-way "hash", not a reversible "encryption" (Bcrypt would be better, but...). It's unclear when/why they sent you a password in plain text. Was it auto-generated? If so, they could have sent it to you when it was generated at the same time they stored the hashed version. Was it sent to you at the time of registration? If so, they could have sent the email at the same time it was hashed and stored.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a security question, not a programming question. OP might try http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: See [The registration confirmation email contains my password: do they keep it in plaintext?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61215/the-registration-confirmation-email-contains-my-password-do-they-keep-it-in-pla)

Comment: No, it was the password I set as my login information. Hopefully it was hashed and stored at the same time. Thanks for clearifying!

Sorry, I saw similar questions, so I thought I could ask it here. I'll try at the security subforum instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it still possible to send plain text password even after encryption?

[Rather than ‘encryption’, which could be reversible, you mean ‘hashing’, assuming the use of the term “SHA-256” was correct. SHA-256 is a one-way hash, the whole point of which is it's not directly recoverable.]

No, but they could conceivably have sent the mail directly after you entered the password, rather than storing it and retrieving it.

In any case a plain SHA-256 salted hash, is considered an unconscionably weak way to store a password today; you would hope for a deliberately slow password-hashing algorithm such as bcrypt.

> Is it safe?

No! They sent you your password over the public unprotected e-mail infrastructure! That is, if anything, a worse sin than storing plaintext passwords in the database...